# I can't see my model files. MVC Project with EF 6.4. Visual Studio has "edmx" files in the Models folder, and nothing else

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm not able to see my models in Visual Studio 2017 in an MVC project with Entity Framework 6.4. This is because the Models folder is empty, except for an "edmx" file.

I tried "Run Custom Tool" on the edmx file but it didn't do anything. I tried restarting Visual Studio, deleting my .vs folders, and deleting temp files.

The model class files and context files have been created *but don't show up in Visual Studio*.

[image: Problem highlighted in red]

Comment: If you click the *Show All Files* button in the Solution Explorer, can you then expand that EDMX node? Haven't used EF in VB for a long time (if ever) and not sure whether those items get hidden by default, like the designer code file for a form. Can you actually use the entity types in code? If so, have you tried right-clicking one and selecting *Navigate to Declaration* or whatever it's called?

Comment: I think that was it @jmcilhinney , please add this as an answer and I'll mark it solved

Comment: To be honest, I'd recommend deleting the question because those code files are hidden for a reason. If you're using database first with a designer then you should only be interacting with your entity classes via the designer. There shouldn't really be a reason to get into that code directly. If you want to add functionality to your entities, e.g. implement an interface, then you can do that by adding another code file with a partial class definition. If you want to keep the question though, feel free to add your own answer, assuming that you're allowed to at this stage.

Comment: Can you give a short example of how to create a partial class implementing some additional features using my table names from above?

Comment: What don't you understand about the information you read about partial classes when you looked for yourself?

Comment: I have almost no experience building code this way. I barely had the confident to take my development in this direction to begin with. To refactor my code project-wide as a best practice instead of using the files generated for me could potentially break my code and permanently halt the project. I was asking you for a *short example* because you're a more experienced developer and your insight would be helpful. If you're not willing provide it I understand but please don't imply I'm being lazy by asking for your help. I'm satisfied with what I've learned here so you have yourself a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking Show All Files in solution explorer worked for me. User who supplied the answer was not willing to post it.